# Magento Product price is equal to 0 display text

Tags: magento, price

i need to replace or hide add to cart button on product list page if product price is equal to zero '0'.

like here : http://www.lighting-furniture-design.com/luxury-lighting/ceiling-suspensions/deep-sky-2565.html

my demo site is here : http://www.sllv2.lighting-design-led.com/luminaire-de-luxe.html

please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the following if else around your add to cart button

```
 <?php if ($_product->getFinalPrice() == 0) : ?>
     <h2>On demand</h2>
 <?php else: ?> 
     // Your add to cart button here
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace the text of botton, when price is zero. copy the file addtocart.phtml in your theme. Change buttonTitle to below. It will check price and accordingly you can change the text.

```
    <?php $buttonTitle = ( ($_product->getFinalPrice() > 0) ? 
          Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) :
          "your text" ); 
    ?>
```